# InputArrayOfArrays in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to generate an InputArrayOfArrays to pass into OpenCV calibrate. I believe it should be a vector of vectors. However, when I call the calibrate function it bombs out with an exception that my input and output arrays aren't the same size. I've tried to perform the conversion outside of the calibrate call and the resulting InputArrayOfArrays (op and ip) appear to not be initialised (the reported total() size is random). If I interrogate the vectors directly, they are as expected.
Any help is much appreciated!

```
{
....
//pixel position is imagePoints
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > imagePoints(1); //={ Point(144,103),  Point(206,75),  Point(109,151), Point(253,159) };
imagePoints[0].push_back(Point(144,103));
imagePoints[0].push_back(Point(206,75));
imagePoints[0].push_back(Point(109,151));
imagePoints[0].push_back(Point(253,159));
//real world position is object Points
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3d> > objectPoints(1); //={ Point3d(4,3,0),  Point3d(7,2,0),  Point3d(2,5,0), Point3d(8,6,0)};
objectPoints[0].push_back(Point3d(4,3,0));
objectPoints[0].push_back(Point3d(7,2,0));
objectPoints[0].push_back(Point3d(2,5,0));
objectPoints[0].push_back(Point3d(8,6,0));

InputArrayOfArrays ip = InputArrayOfArrays(imagePoints);
InputArrayOfArrays op = InputArrayOfArrays(objectPoints);

printf("ip (%d, %I64u) op (%d, %I64u)\n", ip.empty(), ip.total(), op.empty(), op.total());

fisheye::calibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints, distorted.size(), Ka, Da, rvec, tvec, flag, cv::TermCriteria(3, 20, 1e-6));

}
```

Ouptut is:
ip (0, 18446744073709499195) op (0, 18446744073709499176)
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!objectPoints.empty() && !imagePoints.empty() && objectPoints.total() == imagePoints.total()) in cv::fisheye::calibrate, file C:\Temp\OpenCV_3.2_extra\source\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\fisheye.cpp, line 701

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you are defining the vectors and adding points in a right way

try doing it as follows

```
std::vector<cv::Point2d> imagePoints; //={ Point(144,103),  Point(206,75),  Point(109,151), Point(253,159) };
imagePoints.push_back(Point2d(144,103));
imagePoints.push_back(Point2d(206,75));
imagePoints.push_back(Point2d(109,151));
imagePoints.push_back(Point2d(253,159));
//real world position is object Points
std::vector<cv::Point3d> objectPoints; //={ Point3d(4,3,0),  Point3d(7,2,0),  Point3d(2,5,0), Point3d(8,6,0)};
objectPoints.push_back(Point3d(4,3,0));
objectPoints.push_back(Point3d(7,2,0));
objectPoints.push_back(Point3d(2,5,0));
objectPoints.push_back(Point3d(8,6,0));
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't make a difference. I think the reason that it takes an array of arrays is you can specify calibration points for multiple images. I only wish to provide the points for one though.

Comment: There's no much more to it but I'll add it.

Comment: I can't add it all, too long but here is the preceeding bit:

Comment: cv::Mat distorted = MatFromImage(img, MakeGrey);
       cv::Mat undistorted = distorted.clone();

       Mat Knew = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);

    cv::Matx33d Ka;
    cv::Vec4d Da;
    std::vector<cv::Vec3d> rvec;
    std::vector<cv::Vec3d> tvec;

    int flag = 0;
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC;
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_CHECK_COND;
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW;

Comment: MatFromImage is my own routine. It creates a matrix of type: cv::Mat image(imSize, type, dataBuffer, stride);  @vacky